# Hide rows from DataTable on DataGrid in WPF C#

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datatable, datagrid

I'm trying to hide specific rows from DataTable, but I'm only able to hide columns.

I found some solutions related to DataGridView, but it's not the same and didn't work for me.

In my xaml file I have :

```
<DataGrid Visibility="Visible" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="dataGrid_first" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto"  Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" >

</DataGrid>
```

To show data on it, I'm doing as follows:

```
dataGrid_first.ItemsSource = myDataTable.AsDataView();
```

And it's working. To hide columns, I'm doing something like this:

```
dataGrid_first.Columns[i].Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
```

where 'i' is proper column number.

How can I hide a row?

Comment: what are conditions to hide specific rows? one simple approach is to use DataView `Filter` property

Comment: I have two similar datagrid and I'm trying to show differences between two databases. Are you able to wrote some simple example?

Comment: Why give the grid the data and then try to hide some of it. Why not just give it the data you want it to show. In other words filter the data first.

Comment: It's ok for me to give proper data. The problem is that I'm not able to filter proper rows.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend filtering as well, and more I would not use DataTable a bit old. 
You can hide row with

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding DataView}">
                <DataGrid.RowStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                        <!-- your column name, visibility was not working if there is no converter -->
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="{ Binding Path=IsVisible ,Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}"></Setter>
                    </Style>
                </DataGrid.RowStyle>
            </DataGrid>
```

In your ViewModel

```
myDataTable.Rows[i]["IsVisible"] = false;
```

If you don't set a DataContext your component will be the context so you can add DataView property there (But use ViewModels if you can). [BoolToVisibilityConverter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.booleantovisibilityconverter(v=vs.110).aspx)